# I am trying to set attributed string to UITableViewCell's text label I am using following code

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

```
NSDictionary * dic = [arrayForTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSNumber* lostPets = [dic valueForKey:@"lostPets"];
NSNumber * foundPets = [dic valueForKey:@"foundPets"];
NSString * breed = [dic valueForKey:@"breed"];

NSMutableAttributedString* message = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
//set text
[message appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (",breed]]];
[message appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[foundPets stringValue] attributes:@{
                                                                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]
                                                                                             }]];
[message appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"), ("]];
[message appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[lostPets stringValue] attributes:@{
                                                                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
                                                                                             }]];
[message appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@")"]];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = message;
```

When I run the code I get following exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceRGBColor ctFontRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I tried to debug the code but unable to get the point of crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you passing a color to the font attribute?

You are creating this dictionary:

```
@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor] }
```

Those two don't match. Either replace `NSFontAttributeName` with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` or replace `[UIColor greenColor]` with a proper `UIFont` reference. The change depends on what you need. Do you want to set the color or set the font?